# How to implement a 'next' property to a CaseIterable enum in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I'm trying to add a `next` var to an enum.  I am able to do so for a specific enum but would like to extend it generically so that I can obtain the 'next' enum case from an enum value just by specifying an enum with a protocol, ex `CaseNextIterable`

```
enum MyEnum: CaseIterable { // 'next' here is possible thanks to 'CaseIterable' protocol
    case a, b, c
    // returns the next case, or first if at end of sequence
    // ie. a.next == b, c.next == a
    var next: Self {
        var r: Self!
        for c in Self.allCases + Self.allCases { // not efficient
            if r != nil {
                r = c
                break
            }
            if c == self {
                r = self
            }
        }
        return r
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can extend `CaseIterable` constraining `Self` to `Equatable`. Then you just need to find the index after the `firstIndex` of your `CaseItareble` enumeration and return the element at that position. If the index is equal to the `endIndex` of all cases just return the first element.

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    private var allCases: AllCases { Self.allCases }
    var next: Self {
        let index = allCases.index(after: allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!)
        guard index != allCases.endIndex else { return allCases.first! }
        return allCases[index]
    }
}
```

---

Another option is to constrain `AllCases` to `BidirectionalCollection`. This will allow you to get the last element of you enumeration, check if it is equal to self and return the first element without the need to iterate your whole collection:

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable, AllCases: BidirectionalCollection {
    var allCases: AllCases { Self.allCases }
    var next: Self {
        guard allCases.last != self else { return allCases.first! }
        return allCases[allCases.index(after: allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!)]
    }
}
```

---

expanding on CaseIterable next and previous properties:

```
extension CaseIterable {
    typealias Index = AllCases.Index
    var first: Self { allCases.first! }
    private var allCases: AllCases { Self.allCases }
    private static func index(after i: Index) -> Index { allCases.index(after: i) }
}
```

---

```
extension CaseIterable where AllCases: BidirectionalCollection {
    var last: Self { allCases.last! }
    private static func index(before i: Index) -> Index { allCases.index(before: i) }
}
```

---

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    var index: Index { Self.firstIndex(of: self) }
    private static func firstIndex(of element: Self) -> Index { allCases.firstIndex(of: element)! }
}
```

---

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable, AllCases: BidirectionalCollection {
    var previous: Self { first == self ? last : allCases[Self.index(before: index)] }
    var next: Self { last == self ? first : allCases[Self.index(after: index)] }
}
```

---

Playground testing;

```
enum Enum: CaseIterable {
    case a,b,c
}

let value: Enum = .c

let next = value.next  // a
let next2 = next.next  // b
let next3 = next2.next // c

let previous = value.previous      // b
let previous2 = previous.previous  // a
let previous3 = previous2.previous // c
```

Comment: Is there any special reason for the first line other than getting it shorter?

Comment: @itMaxence no. It was just to make it easier to read and avoid repetition

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this in complement of Leo Dabus' answer, in case people would need the `previous` extension too.

---

edit:

I added both `next` and `previous`.

The main difference is in the behavior expected.

For `out of band`:

- this solution returns `nul`
- Leo Dabus' solution works like a `chained list`

```swift
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    var allCases: AllCases { Self.allCases }

    /// Using `next` on an empty enum of on the last element returns `nil`
    var next: Self? {
        guard let currentIndex = allCases.firstIndex(of: self) else { return nil }

        let index = allCases.index(after: currentIndex)

        // ensure we don't go past the last element
        guard index != allCases.endIndex else { return nil }
        return allCases[index]
    }

    var previous: Self? {
        guard let currentIndex = allCases.firstIndex(of: self) else { return nil }

        // ensure we don't go before the first element
        guard currentIndex != allCases.startIndex else { return nil }
        let index = allCases.index(currentIndex, offsetBy: -1)

        return allCases[index]
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented it here as well

Comment: But on my implementation if it is the first It returns the last

Comment: Indeed depends on the behavior you want . Though this case would be stupid, having an empty Enum would crash without optional. But I guess I'm just paranoïd here haha

Comment: Nice and clean edit! Since the main difference is about behavior, I'll edit my answer too

Comment: you can’t create an empty CaseIterable enumeration

Comment: Oh you're right! You can declare an empty `CaseIterable` enum but! Can't actually create an instance of it by any way. So the `guard` on empty case is actually useless