# how to use an array as a case of an enum

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, enums

I'm using Swift 5.3 and Xcode 12.4 and I have an enum that contains types, and one case is basically an array of the other cases.
it looks like this:

```
enum Types {
static let type1                             = "type1"
static let type2                             = "type2"
static let type3                             = "type3"
static let type4                             = "type4"
static let type5                             = "type5" 

static let typeArray                         = [type1, type2, type3]
```

}

I need to change it to the following, but Xcode says "Raw value for enum case must be a literal"

```
enum Types: String, Codable, CaseIterable {
    case type1
    case type2
    case type3
    case type4
    case type5
    case typesArray                         = [type1, type2, type3]
}
```

Any ideas how to change the enum on top to the one at the bottom please? thank you!

Comment: Why would you need this array case? Why not simply `Types.allCases`? Just remove your `typesArray` case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Leo, I edited my question to hopefully explain it better. The array will contain some of the cases, not all of them.

Comment: This `Type` is not `Types`. It is `Type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a static property:

---

```
enum Types: String, Codable, CaseIterable {
    case type1, type2, type3, type4, type5
    static let someCases: [Types] = [.type1, .type2, .type3] 
}
```

---

```
Types.someCases  // [type1, type2, type3]
```

Comment: I'll give it a try now and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: If you need to iterate your cases check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61251176/2303865)

Comment: I voted "up" for your answer, I don't know how to mark it as correct. If there is a way to do so, can you please show me how?

Comment: oh, didn't know that's the purpose of that checkmark. I checked it as a correct answer, thank you very mush for your help